# What is error in this code? Browser says "java.lang.NullPointerException" in this code

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, null

Mainly error is shown in "if" section. 
"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/enquiryForm_processing.jsp] at line [52]" is the error.

Code:

```
<%@page import="com.Package3.*"%>

<%String saved=EnquirySaving.savingFunction(name, address, email, mobile, gName, gMobile, time, career1, career2, career3, career4, hear1, hear2, hear3, hear4, hear5, before, institution, courses, status, councelling, visitDate, othersSpecify, othersSpecify1, othersSpecify2);%>  


<%if(saved.equals("success")){%>
    <%response.sendRedirect("loginPage.jsp");%>
<%}else{%>
    <%response.sendRedirect("enquiryForm_processing_failed.jsp");%>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `NullPointerException` exception is coming from the `if` block line, it means that the expression `saved.equals("success")` is causing the problem, from which we can deduce that `saved` variable is `null` and you are trying to call a `method` on it.

You need to check for it's `nullability` before trying to call a method on it:

```
if(saved != null  && saved.equals("success"))
```

A better recommendation is to inverse your expression and call `.equals()` on your constant `string`, in order to avoid the `NullPointerException`:

```
"success".equals(saved)
```